# How to interpret this log message?

Tags: java, android, logging, android-resources

I was trying to add a text view to a `LinearLayout` programmatically using the following:

```
    Resources r = getResources ();
    TextView text = new TextView (this);
    text.setText (R.string.no_passwords);
    Log.d ("My App", r.getString (R.string.no_passwords));
    text.setTextSize (r.getDimension (R.dimen.prompt_size));
    Log.d ("My App", "Text size: " + r.getDimension (R.dimen.prompt_size));

    LinearLayout.LayoutParams params = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams (ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
    parent.setGravity (Gravity.CENTER);

    text.setLayoutParams (params);
    parent.addView (text);
```

Explanation:

`parent` is the `LinearLayout` with the id `parent_layout` (You will see this in the code below).  I am logging with the tag "My App" because I am using a custom filter to log stuff.

But the view is not added. I looked at the log message and see something relly weird:

```
10-17 09:33:26.764  11877-11877/com.passwordgen D/My App﹕ [ 10-17 09:33:26.764 11877:11877 D/My App   ]
    Text size: 43.132
```

`R.string.no_password` should be "You have not saved any passwords yet" and `R.dimen.prompt_size` should be 9pt.

Quuestions:

Why the first log message isn't showing the right text but `[ 10-17 09:33:26.764 11877:11877 D/My App   ]`? And why the second message is not prefixed by the tag "My App"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need to call `invalidate()` to make the view be redrawn. Also it is recommended you do this via an xml file vs. in code.

Comment: So why is the log message so strange?

Comment: most likely because the result of the `getString` call might be null